# How to Distinguish touchpad, touchscreen, or mouse which was touching by user, using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have one computer with Win8, IE11, TouchPad, TouchScreen, and Mouse in one like Acer Aspire s7. Is there any way to distinguish which device was used (touched) so that I could use a different method to deal with the different movement.

I know there's lots of functions to detect whether the PC (notebook) is touch device or not,
but I want to ask which equipment was triggering (touchPad, touchScreen or mouse) on the device.

Thanks for any suggestion or solution, Thank you.

Comment: Look at this, if you haven't already: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Touch_events

Comment: @meskobalazs Thanks for sharing, but i saw that **Browser compatibility** IE not supported, so is there any other way to achieve these things?

Answer (score -2):

### You could use jquery touch events

### Like

```
$("body").on("swipe",function(){
 //
});

$("body").on("tap",function(){
 //
});
```

also `touchstart` event and `swipe left or right` are available.

```
[touchend,touchcancel,touchleave,touchmove]
```

### Mouse events are:

```
click,drag etc.
```

### Inside the Event Handler Function

Every event handling function receives an event object, which contains many properties and methods. The event object is most commonly used to prevent the default action of the event via the .preventDefault() method. However, the event object contains a number of other useful properties and methods, including:

### type

The type of the event (e.g., "click").

### which

The button or key that was pressed.

### Example

```
$(window).load(mycall);
$(window).resize(mycall);
var mycall = function(e) { 
    alert(e.type);
};
```

### Handling Multiple Events for same element

```
$('#textBox').bind('blur keyup', function(e){
   if( e.type === 'click' || (e.type === 'keyup' && e.which === 13) ){
     // Code...
   }
   if(e.type ==='tap'){
     //Code for touch tap
   }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing, but could I get the info about which item was touching, or only have to differentiate which function was triggered?

Comment: I hope you got the point from my updated answer. For more informations see this link http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-basics/

Comment: thanks for updating, and i thought if i wanna bind/unbind multiple function with the situation when the different kind of device(touchScreen or trackPad) triggered; According to your opinion, i have to set kind of event like tap, swipe etc. to detect which device touched, is it a little bit of strange? Or it's javascript limitation? Thanks again.

Comment: For example, i will know touchScreen touched/touching if i put two more(tap, swipe...), and mouse by mouseWheel, mouseClick etc. And there are four more events to get the two different facts. Thanks!

Comment: you could use like my updated code reg. handling multiple events for a single element.